# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API Role based authorization not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I couldn't understand why I always get *401 unauthorized* where the user I logged in has a role of *SuperAdmin*. I tried looking at other solutions and projects and they seem identical to the code I have still does not work. I use Postman to test the API and in Authorization tab bearer token I pasted the token of the user I logged in and make a request on this API.

```
    //API
    [Route("create")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUserAsync([FromBody] Request request)
    {
       return something;
    }

    //StartUp.cs
    private void ConfigureAuth(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<UserEntity, RoleEntity>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddRoles<RoleEntity>();
    }
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

    //JWT
    public string GenerateToken(UserEntity userEntity, IList<string> roles)
    {
        var token = string.Empty;
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.jwtOptions.GetJwtOptions().Secret));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userEntity.UserName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userEntity.FirstName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, userEntity.LastName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userEntity.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles.FirstOrDefault()) //SuperAdmin
        };

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(this.jwtOptions.GetJwtOptions().ExpiresInMinutes),
            SigningCredentials = credentials
        };

        token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor));

        return token;
    }
```

Comment: When that token is generated, is the first role in `roles` actually "SuperAdmin"?

Comment: Did you use `AddJwtBearer` extension in startup.cs to validate/decode token and write to user claims ?

Comment: @Marco The user I logged in has only one role. Yes, it is "SuperAdmin". I Checked it on debug.

Comment: @NanYu I updated the code. What I'm still missing?

Comment: Das your configure method in your Startup.cs contain the call to use the Authorization middlware `.UseAuthorization()` and is it invoked after `.UseAuthentication()`?

Comment: @Marco I only have `app.UseAuthorization();` in the Configure() method.

Comment: @RonaldAbellano , you should add `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization()` , otherwise authentication middleware fail to handle jwt and return 401 error

Comment: I need to read more about IApplicationBuilder. Thanks guys!

Comment: Make it an answer. So I can mark this as solved.

Comment: I don't think that you need to spend more time with the IAppBuilder, but just keep in mind, that the configure method actually wires up the middleware pipeline and that it is dependend on order.  The request goes through top-to-bottom and the response from bottom-to-top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseAuthorization()` , the authentication middleware will handle the JWT bearer authentication , validate and decode token , at last write to user's principle.